# how can find location of value in a square using excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i have tried to find location of max value written between B4 and F11.

using `=MATCH(MAX(B4:F11),B4:F11,0)` returns n/a.

Comment: can you provide more details

Comment: 'location of a square' ?? Do you mean the address of a cell ?

Answer (score 1):

For the cell *address*:

`=LET(ζ,B4:F11,BASE(MIN(IF(ζ=MAX(ζ),DECIMAL(ADDRESS(ROW(ζ),COLUMN(ζ),4),36))),36))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MATCH` only with one column directly. If you have multicolumns and want to find row number in given table you can use this:

```
=MATCH(1,MMULT(--(B4:F11=MAX(B4:F11)),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B4:F11)^0)),0)
```

Comment: That won't actually return the row *number*; it will return the *relative position* from (in this case) row 4. And of course it doesn't tell you in which column the maximum lies.

Comment: Yes, that is why i mentioned "in given table". Lets say if max position is in D4 for example it will give result 1 as it is 1st row in that table. OP should give more details on what does it mean "location"

Comment: Adding `ROW(B4)-1` would fix it, the question would need some clarification about the specific information requested and the format in which to return it. The is no expected output.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the question how to understand "*location*" (row, column, both, absolute or relative location) and in which format to return the information requested. Here, is an approach that returns the absolute row and column location:

```
=LET(x, B2:E5, xi, B2, LOC, LAMBDA(y,offset, offset + XMATCH(1, 
 BYROW(y, LAMBDA(a, MAX(N(a=MAX(y))))))), HSTACK(LOC(x, ROW(xi)-1), 
  LOC(TRANSPOSE(x), COLUMN(xi)-1)))
```

It uses a user `LAMBDA` function `LOC` to avoid the repetition of a similar process for the row to get the column. If you need just relative location within the array, then the second argument (`offset`) is not needed, so it can be simplified as follow:

```
=LET(x, B2:E5, LOC, LAMBDA(y, XMATCH(1, BYROW(y, LAMBDA(a, MAX(N(a=MAX(y))))))),
 HSTACK(LOC(x), LOC(TRANSPOSE(x))))
```

For just relative row location it would be enough:

```
=XMATCH(1, BYROW(B2:E5, LAMBDA(a, MAX(N(a=MAX(B2:E5))))))
```

Here is the output:

[image: sample excel file]